# Is there anything Quantikz can do that Tikz cannot do?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am learning how to draw quantum circuits. I was checking the options available and I could see that Ti*k*Z and Quantikz are suitable for making circuits diagrams but I want to know if there are some tasks that Quantikz can do but Ti*k*Z cannot. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please specify why you added `circuitikz` tag here?

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I removed it because it was not appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

The `Quantikz` package is a subset of Ti*k*Z. Whatever you can do with `Quantikz` can be done with Ti*k*Z (and the other required packages by `Quantikz`). Here are the packages required for `Quantikz` (copied from `tikzlibraryquantikz.code.tex` lines 49-52).

```
\RequirePackage{xargs,ifthen,xstring,xparse,etoolbox,mathtools,pgfmath}
\RequirePackage{environ} % in an attempt to help with compatibility 
                         % with the external library of tikz.
\usetikzlibrary{cd,decorations.pathreplacing,calc,positioning,fit,
shapes.symbols,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes.misc,backgrounds,
decorations.markings,math}
```

The other packages (that I know) that you can use are [qcircuit](https://ctan.org/pkg/qcircuit?lang=en) and [qpic](https://github.com/qpic/).

I started with `qcircuit` but then completely migrated to `Quantikz`. My humble experience allows me to only compare `qcircuit` to `Quantikz`. I clearly noticed `qcircuit` is limited and lacks compared to `Quantikz`. For example, the `slice` option in `Quantikz` is done automatically whereas `qcircuit` requires to be done manually. Also, grouping (drawing boxes around parts of the circuit) in `Quantikz` is much more easier and robust than `qcircuit`. Colouring of gates is not simple using `qcircuit` but effortless using `Quantikz`. Lastly (and I am not 100% certain about this), I do think that whatever you can do in `qcircuit` can also be done using `Quantikz`.

Comment: Isn't Quantick rather a software overlay of TikZ?

Comment: @AndréC can you please define software overlay?

Comment: I don't know the exact translation of `surcouche logicielle (software layer)`  in English. A software layer is a software or computer language that is written from another, lower level language. For example, LaTeX is a software overlayer of TeX.

Comment: @AndréC yes, correct. `Quantikz` is a subset/based on Ti*k*Z.

Comment: @AndréC No, not a software layer; more horizontal. Quantikz is a latex package: from CTAN (https://ctan.org/pkg/quantikz?lang=en): "The purpose of this package is to extend TikZ with the functionality for drawing quantum circuit diagrams."